# How to upload image to postgreSQL database using ember and RESTful api

Tags: ember.js, django-rest-framework, image-upload

I have an ember app to list the details about `alumni` using django rest framework and postgreSQL. I need to upload image(stored in the my storage) along with other details. How can I achieve this in ember?

Can I do it by converting to base64 from ember and storing the encoded string? If possible, how?

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: @JPG I was able to encode the image to base64 using [this](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-image-drop) addon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to upload the image to PostgreSQL by using base64 encoding. I used the [ember-image-drop](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-image-drop) addon to convert the image to base64 code.

I used these codes in my `add` route(Note that I am using pod-structure):

**template.hbs**

```
<form {{action "submitAlumni" on="submit"}} class="alumniForm">
    <div>{{image-drop image=selectedImage placeholder="Image" helpText="Drop your image here, or click to select"}}</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" {{action "submitAlumni"}}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**route.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
});
```

**controller.js**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { set } from '@ember/object';

export default Controller.extend({
    image: null,

    actions: {
        submitAlumni() {
            let image = this.get('selectedImage');
            var onFail = function(response) {
                alert(response);
            };
            const alumni = this.get('store').createRecord('alumni', {
                image: image,
            });
            alumni.save().then(() => {
                this.transitionToRoute('alumnis.show', alumni.id)
            }, onFail);
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this module for this [image-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-base64-converter)

Comment: can i do the same to convert image file from my local storage

Comment: yes if you have a file you can convert this to base64